# Terminology for stochastic processes: "marginalizing" over time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, stochastic-analysis

Suppose I have a stochastic process $X(t)$ which outputs symbols in some state space $S$.

Given each possible symbol $s$ in $S$, I would like to determine some kind of "marginal" probability representing how frequently each symbol occurs, in a sort of average of the entire behavior of the stochastic process on the entire time coordinate.

However, the time coordinate is not actually a random variable, so we are not technically marginalizing anything, so the question I am asking is really what to call this thing. Basically, we are asking how likely the stochastic process is to output each symbol "in general."

To keep it simple, let's assume that our time index $t \in \Bbb N$. Then in particular, the quantity I would like to look at is this:

$$
P(X = s) := \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\text{expected # of occurrences of s from t=0..N}}{N}
$$

where the $P(X = s)$ is the notation I am using for this quantity.

In other words, we compute the expected number of occurrences of our stochastic process emitting $s$ within the first $N$ time steps. Then we let $N$ go to infinity. This is the probability of the stochastic process outputting the symbol $s$ "in general."

(For now let's suppose that $S$ is a finite or at most countable set, although this question could also be asked for a real-valued stochastic process, where we'd look at something like a probability density instead.)

Basic questions:

1. Most importantly: **does this quantity have a name?** It's almost like we are "marginalizing" on the time coordinate, except the time isn't a random variable.
2. For what stochastic processes is this quantity guaranteed to exist?
3. Is there some formally rigorous way to do this same thing with e.g. a time coordinate in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in the comments it turns into a linguistic debate rather than a mathematical discussion.

Comment: This question is about terminology. Your answer didn't actually answer the question, so I didn't accept it. That's about all there is to say regarding that, I think.

Comment: You have your favourite terminology and I have mine. So what ?

Answer (score -1):

There is some confusion. A stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{T}}$ (regardless if $\mathbb T$ is $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R_+$) can be seen as a map
$$
X:\mathbb T\times\Omega\to S\,.
$$
The probability measure $P$ is defined on $(\Omega,{\cal A})$ and not on $\mathbb T\,.$

- The expression $P(X=s)$ is quite ambiguous. For which $t\in\mathbb T$ are you looking at $X_t$ being $s$ ?
- It sounds like you are rather interested in (the limit of)
  $$\tag{1}
  \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1_{\{X_n=s\}}}{N}
  $$
  which is a random variable on $(\Omega,{\cal A})$, or in (the limit of)
  $$\tag{2}
  E\Bigg[\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1_{\{X_n=s\}}}{N}\Bigg]
  $$
  which is the expectation of (1).
- When the $X_n$ are i.i.d. then by he srong law of large numbers
  $$\tag{3}
  \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1_{\{X_n=s\}}}{N}=E\Big[1_{\{X_1=s\}}\Big]=P(X_1=s)\,.
  $$
  The same holds for the limit of (2).
- When $\mathbb T=\mathbb R_+$ then we could consider
  $$\tag{4}
  \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T1_{\{X_t=s\}}\,dt\,
  $$
  instead of (2). This is however not very useful when $X$ is a Brownian motion.
  Therefore, see [Local time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_(mathematics)).
- (1) and (4) can be called the pathwise average time that $X$ equals $s\,.$

Comment: I am not following some of this. What is the difference between $S$ and $\Sigma$ here? And when you say the probability measure is not defined on $T$, is that in response to some part of the post?

Comment: Are you saying this quantity is called "pathwise average time?"

Comment: $S$ is how you denoted your state space in your OP. $\Sigma$ is the usual symbol for a sum. Do you agree that $P$ is defined on $\Omega$ and not on $\mathbb T$? This is what counts - not what you think I thought when I wrote that. Lastly: I think this quantity can reasonably be called "pathwise average time". Don't ask me how it is called by the rest of the world. I cannot speak for those.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo on my part. I meant, what is the difference between $S$ and $\Omega$? I am referring to when you write :×Ω→. I was using $S$ to mean the set of possible outputs of the stochastic process at some point in time, which I thought would have been the same as the sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: I was not viewing $T$ as a random variable with some kind of probability distribution on it, if that's what you mean. I was viewing a stochastic process as a collection of random variables $X_t$ where $t$ is just an index into the set. The random variables need not be IID but they must take values in the same state space. But I can see that Wikipedia has some difference between the "state space" and "sample space" of a stochastic process and I'm not quite sure what that is.

Comment: Ok. Stochastic processes are random variables that also depend on time. Since time is from $\mathbb T$ we can concentrate on the question what a random variable $X_t$ is. Let's drop that $t$. A random variable $Y$ is a map from an abstract probability space to a state space $S$. Typical state spaces have points that can be measured, for example $S$ is typically $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^d$. In contrast, $\Omega$ is totally abstract. Its sole purpose is to carry the probability measure $P$ and to provide randomness.

Comment: OK, that's quite interesting; I guess I had missed this quirk of the mathematical definition of a random variable before. So in a probability triple, $\Omega$ refers to the space of possible outcomes; a typical example would be that a coin flip has $\Omega = \text{{heads, tails}}$. But for a random variable, $\Omega$ is some kind of totally abstract thing - like the output of a random number generator or something - and the random variable maps from outcomes in this totally abstract thing to the state space we really want. Is that correct?

Comment: It is a good start :) . The models one sees in elementary proability theory (coin tossing, urns, etc.) can be described by fairly concrete probability spaces (you mendioned heads/tails). In contrast: to construct $(\Omega,{\cal F},P)$ for a Brownian motion (aka Wiener process) one has to go a long way. Then there is the abstract theory of stochastic processes where it is just stated as an axiom that $(\Omega,{\cal F},P)$ shall exist, and so forth. The ***main*** difference between $\Omega$ and state space $S=\mathbb R^d$ is in my opinion that only that numerical $S$ allows to calculate ...

Comment: expected ***values***, variances, covariances and so on. you could not do that when $X$ had values in $\Omega=\{heads, tails\}$

Comment: OK, makes sense. This post also clears up the confusion I had about that: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10789/why-are-random-variables-defined-as-functions -- so then yes I did mean that $S$ is the state space, and I guess $\Omega$ can be this abstract thing. To answer your question about time, then, I wasn't treating time as a random variable, but rather the random variable $X$ as a function of time (or if you like, a function from $\Omega \times \Bbb T \to S$. (1/2)

Comment: It *would* be nice if I could say that $\Bbb T$ were some kind of random variable, and then marginalize on the $\Bbb T$ to get some kind of marginal probability of the various symbols in $S$ being produced, but I'm not sure how one could formalize this. Either way though, I am still hoping this quantity has a name and to determine for what stochastic processes it exists (clearly for many processes besides just IID ones). (2/2)

Comment: $\mathbb T$ is the set from which we take time $n$. This $\mathbb T$ cannot be a random variable. What can be a RV is the number of $n$'s where $X_n$ equals $s$. If you are happy with that use formula (1).

Comment: After looking at this I think we are basically talking about the average of the marginal probabilities $P(X_t)$ for $t \in [0..N]$, then letting $N \to \infty$. That is, an equivalent formalization of your "expected value of indicator function" idea is just the arithmetic mean of the marginal probabilities at each time up to $N$. Is that the idea?

Comment: Are we homing in on formula  (1) ? If so it should be not hard to interpret it. I tried my best to do that and I tried my best to give it a name. Feel freeto give it your favourite  name if that helps with the understsanding. "marginal" would not be mine because this is used in the context of joint probabilities. Names, names, names ...

Comment: I'm just literally saying that I think it's mathematically equivalent to the average of the marginal probability vectors for the first $N$ random variables in the sequence and asking if you agreed with that. I wasn't saying that as $N\to \infty$ the result would also be a marginal probability...